# RewriteRule not redirecting

Tags: php, drupal-7

Due to request, every page needs to be prefixed with "index.php"; if the path was first /it, now it needs to be /index.php/it.

I have tried changing base url in settings.php. But it doesnot works.Tried rewriting in .htaccess also. I have tried the following code

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www.example.com/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

But it doesnot works. Somebody help me please. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled and try with this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/index.php/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Remember that the `$1` refers to the `(.*)` you have captured in the URL

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Actually my url is http://192.168.1.89:1008/it. now, i have changed .htacces file with ur code. now it is redirecting to http://192.168.1.89:1008/index.php/it. But, I'm getting page not found error.

Comment: So I understand that the new address is what you were looking for, right? If you get a page not found error, this means you need to configure your server to handle requests to 192.168.1.89:1008/index.php/it

Answer (score 0):

You are not using your capture group `(.*)`. You can refer to it using `$1`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/index.php/$1 [L,R=301]
```